# How to send to the client that its token is expired?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I'm using JWT auth in my ASP.NET Core app:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = domain;
    options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:ApiIdentifier"];
});
```

How can I notify the client that its token is expired?
May be some body in 401 response or another response code?

Comment: Why you have to notify your user? when the token is expired then your authorized endpoint will deny the request returning an unauthorized response status, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return `401 Unauthorized` as status code , and  containing an error code/description in `WWW-Authenticate` header :

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is expired"
```

You can also manally write the error message :

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
    OnChallenge = context =>
    {
        // Skip the default logic.
        context.HandleResponse();

        var payload = new JObject
        {
            ["error"] = context.Error,
            ["error_description"] = context.ErrorDescription,
            ["error_uri"] = context.ErrorUri
        };

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload.ToString());
    }
};
```